# subprocess stdout and stderr while doing ssh

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I want to know the disk usage of remote servers and i thought of doing it using ssh
here's what i have done so far:-

```
def disk_usage(server):
    msg=""
    ps = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "-o", "BatchMode=yes", "-l", "mygroup", server, "df -k /some/directory"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = ps.communicate()
    if err != None:
        msg += "\n"+err
    else:
        msg = out
    return msg

Final_msg = ""
server_list= ['server A','server B','server C']

for server in server_list:
   Final_msg+="For Server :"+server+"\n"+disk_usage(server)
print Final_msg
```

The script works fine, but problem is when the ssh for any server is not configured it just displays a blank output for that server

Output:-

```
For Server A :
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used     Available     Use%   Mounted on
/dev/cfd/ace      8064048         3581524   4072892         47%     /app
For Server B :

For server C :
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used     Available      Use%   Mounted on
/dev/wsa/ace      306423            244524   23243434       90%     /app
```

Here ssh for server B is not configured so i'm getting a blank output because the batchmode is on (`BatchMode=yes`) for all the ssh connections, but i want the user to know why there was no output.

when i run the same command on the shell for the sever where ssh is not configured i get the below error:

```
 Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

I want the same error in my output of the script for that particular server where ssh is not configured.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect that an error happened, you should check the `returncode` attribute of the Popen object (`ps`).

To get the output from `stderr`, you have to pass `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to Popen, just as you do for `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

if your local machine has static ip i would recommend using sockets so your data usage script will connect to your local machine and deliver data.
or if you have domain to post your server info to your web app via urllib.